# Refreshing Two Pivot Tables on a Sheet whenever the sheet is selected

Tags: vba, excel

I have two PivotTables on a sheet that I would like to have refreshed automatically whenever the sheet is open.  I've put that macro this macro within that sheet.  However, I am getting an error on this line "oPivot.RefreshTable"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oPivot As PivotTable

Set oSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each oPivot In oSheet.PivotTables
    oPivot.RefreshTable
Next oPivot

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try using `oPivot.PivotCache.Refresh`

Comment: That does not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim oPivot As PivotTable
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet

Set xlsheet = ActiveSheet

For Each oPivot In xlsheet.PivotTables
    oPivot.PivotCache.Refresh
Next oPivot 

End Sub
```

Comment: The line "Next pivot_table" highlights and states the error message (Invalid Next control Variable reference".  Any ideas?

Comment: Change that to `Next oPivot`

Comment: Updated, forgot to change the last variable name